# I am getting a "SyntaxError: invalid syntax" when I am trying to install React Slingshot

Tags: reactjs, react-slingshot

I am getting this error when I am trying to install React Slingshot. How can I get rid of this?

Same problem when I am running 'npm run setup' cmd. I am using node version v14.16.0 npm version 7.5.2.

```
    npm ERR! code 1
    npm ERR! path C:\Users\kapil\Downloads\react-slingshot-master\react-slingshot-master\node_modules\node-sass
    npm ERR! command failed
    npm ERR! command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node scripts/build.js
    npm ERR! Building: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\kapil\Downloads\react-slingshot-master\react-slingshot-master\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
    npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
    npm ERR! gyp verb cli [
    npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
    npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'C:\\Users\\kapil\\Downloads\\react-slingshot-master\\react-slingshot-master\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js',
    npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
    npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
    npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
    npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
    npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
    npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='
    npm ERR! gyp verb cli ]
    npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
    npm ERR! gyp info using node@14.16.0 | win32 | x64
    npm ERR! gyp verb command rebuild []
    npm ERR! gyp verb command clean []
    npm ERR! gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
    npm ERR! gyp verb command configure []
    npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
    npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python2
    npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\kapil\Downloads\react-slingshot-master\react-slingshot-master\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
    npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\kapil\Downloads\react-slingshot-master\react-slingshot-master\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
    npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Users\kapil\Downloads\react-slingshot-master\react-slingshot-master\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
    npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\kapil\Downloads\react-slingshot-master\react-slingshot-master\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
    npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\kapil\Downloads\react-slingshot-master\react-slingshot-master\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
    npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\kapil\Downloads\react-slingshot-master\react-slingshot-master\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
    npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:183:21)
    npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed  python2 Error: not found: python2
    npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\kapil\Downloads\react-slingshot-master\react-slingshot-master\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
    npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\kapil\Downloads\react-slingshot-master\react-slingshot-master\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
    npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Users\kapil\Downloads\react-slingshot-master\react-slingshot-master\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
    npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\kapil\Downloads\react-slingshot-master\react-slingshot-master\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
    npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\kapil\Downloads\react-slingshot-master\react-slingshot-master\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
    npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\kapil\Downloads\react-slingshot-master\react-slingshot-master\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
    npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:183:21) {
    npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT'
    npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed }
    npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python" in the PATH
    npm ERR! gyp verb `which` succeeded python C:\Python39\python.EXE
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Command failed: C:\Python39\python.EXE -c import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack   File "<string>", line 1
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack                       ^
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack SyntaxError: invalid syntax
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack 
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:308:12)
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1048:16)
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:288:5)
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19042
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\kapil\\Downloads\\react-slingshot-master\\react-slingshot-master\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\kapil\Downloads\react-slingshot-master\react-slingshot-master\node_modules\node-sass
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v14.16.0
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
    npm ERR! Build failed with error code: 1
    
    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
    npm ERR!     C:\Users\kapil\AppData\Local\npm

-cache\_logs\2021-03-01T07_07_49_867Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Could you run `python --version` on the command line? I wonder if you have version 2 and need version 3.

Comment: I use Python 3.9.1 and I have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Specify Python 2 during your installation, like this:

```
npm i some-package --python=python2.7
```

Edit:
It looks like you're missing python 2. Install Python 2 and specify it during your installation.